# How do i know that jetty started successfully with application instance from an ant target?

Tags: ant, jetty

I face the following problem: whenever i try to start Jetty with an application instance i need check if the application is running. I need to do that from an ant target.
I want to have something behaving like the following pseudocode:

**

```
<target name="target1"
            depends="run-jetty-with-application"
            description="Target1">
        <--when run-jetty-with-application is ok(jetty is up and application is running)-->
        <antcall target="target2"/>
        <--end when-->
    </target>
```

**
I should also mention that i have no publicly exposed urls that could give me the status of the application.
I'm not after the hacky solution like waitfor.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 ways to know if Jetty is started, all webapps are deployed without error, all lifecycle is started successfully, and the server is available to serve content.

1. Periodically ask for a resource on that web app, confirming that it is up and running. (timeout with failure if resources doesn't make itself available after a period of time)
2. Hook into the [LifeCycle.Listener](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/LifeCycle.Listener.html) on the [Server](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html) component, wait for the `.lifeCycleStarted(LifeCycle event)` for the server, then walk the entire handler tree, looking for any Handler component that failed to deploy via the DeploymentManager.

As you can imagine, the first technique is the easiest.

This is the `<waitfor>` facility in Ant, [and is what the Jetty project itself uses](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/e72fed9d4efb682ffff3b9c5cd3923ef12280770/tests/test-cdi/cdi-webapp-it/pom.xml#L139-L153).

The second approach requires a custom Ant task.

You can either write it yourself, and know that it will do what you want.  Or use the [jetty-ant tasks](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/ant/JettyRunTask.html) with daemon mode to get **almost** the same thing (the JettyRunTask in daemon mode starts up the server, but it does not wait for start to finish or the webapps to deploy successfully before it returns control to ant).

Comment: I managed to check if Jetty is up with application running by making a java ant task. The way to bootstrapping a java ant task class can be found here http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html . It is in the java class that i check if Jetty is up and running.

Comment: A little tip, if you are not using the Jetty Distribution, then you are likely using [tag:embedded-jetty], it would be wise if you use that tag or mention that you are using embedded jetty in your question.