# Eclipse Jetty Server Single Instance Application

Tags: java, linux, websocket, jetty

I have created a java SE application. I have exported a runnable jar which runs on linux machine. and created exe file using the same jar which runs on windows.

**if I run the exe several times, multiple instance are getting created ( javaw.exe in the task manager) How can I prevent this?**

I want to prevent that. for that, initially I am trying to check if server is running, but I am using it inside `static main()` method. and `isRunning()` method of Server class is non-static.

I need to run the application on both windows and linux os.

Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try { 
        if(Server.isRunning()){ // compilation error    
        }
        Server server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);

        // Initialize javax.websocket layer
        ServerContainer wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context);

        // Add WebSocket endpoint to javax.websocket layer
        wscontainer.addEndpoint(EventSocket.class);

        server.start();
        server.dump(System.err);
        server.join();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.error("Server Error : " + t.getMessage(), t);
    }
}
```

Comment: My explaination is kind of long but hope it helps: Put a `System.out.println("Server started");` statement right after `Server server = new Server();` . Run the jar file from `cmd` or `terminal`. This way if the server is running, you will see the cursor blinking right after the print out statement. If it is not, in windows for example you will see `C:\Windows\System32>`, which shows that server service has been stopped or terminated.

Comment: Or check [this reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231413/how-do-i-know-that-jetty-started-successfully-with-application-instance-from-an)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal to create a single instance server app should be pretty easy. You can rely on the fact that you can not bind to port 8080 twice. At least that's how it works on Linux. :)

This means `server.start();` will probably fail with some meaningful exception - you catch it and terminate the application. This should happen to all other instances until the port is released.

Of course, there are ways to create single instance apps natively (the EXE wrapper should have an option for that, etc) but here I would go with the port locking.

Comment: on windows it creates multiple instances on the same port. How do I check whether the server is running or not?

Comment: **multiple instances on the same port** What is that supposed to mean. How is that possible?

Comment: it may not be multiple instance, but when I double click the .exe file multiple times, mutilple javaw.exe I can see in the task manager.

Comment: This means your application is running, not that it could connect to the port. If you check `start()` you will see it is not connecting. Then you just have to terminate the application with `System.exit()`.

Comment: System.exit(0) in the catch block was the solution! Thanks @Boris